# How to rotate axes labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm unable to rotate the names on both the y and x axes such that they overlap. What am I doing wrong?

yticks/xticks(rotation=90) also does not adjust the names to prevent them from overlapping.

```
name = 'Anne Frank Diary'
df4 = df.loc[ my_list, my_list ].copy()
axes = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df4, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o',hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8)
corr = df4.corr().values 
for i, j in zip(*plt.np.triu_indices_from(axes, k=1)):
    axes[i, j].annotate("%.3f" %corr[i,j], (0.8, 0.8), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='left', va='center',rotation=90)
sst="%s \n Scatter Matrix of Centrality Indices \n (displaying Pearson correlation coefficients)" %name
plt.suptitle(sst,fontsize=20);
```

[image]

Update:
https://github.com/markamcgown/Projects/blob/master/df.csv
my_list = ['Kugler',
 'Margot',
 'Anne',
 'Pirn',
 'Kleiman',
 'German',
 'Dutch',
 'Dussel',
 'Annex',
 'Peter',
 'Kitty',
 'Bep',
 'Mouschi',
 'British',
 'Miep',
 'van D.']

Answer (score 0):

```
n = len(G.nodes)

for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        # to get the axis of subplots
        ax = axes[x, y]
        # to make x axis name vertical  
        ax.xaxis.label.set_rotation(90)
        # to make y axis name horizontal 
        ax.yaxis.label.set_rotation(0)
        # to make sure y axis names are outside the plot area
        ax.yaxis.labelpad = 10
``
```